# How to change Label value in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

In my application (written in c#) I have a textbox and a submit button.
If the user clicks "submit" without entering any value, I want him to stay at the same page and display a message saying "Please insert value"
I thought to put a label, and then just edit its value and/or visibility.

The structure of my application is as following:
Controller A
inside View, under A, I have B.aspx
and inside B.aspx I call a partial C.ascx
The submit form with my label are inside C.ascx

How can I change the lable value and/or visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Data Validation Attributes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs) for this.

Something like this:

```
[Required]
String textBoxValue{get;set;}
```

This will create a custom javascript/jquery file that will perform the appropriate validation for you.

You can even change the default error message for Required.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "The textbox value is required because I said so :)")]
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 2 support both server-side and client side validation. I believe this version takes a dependency on the jQuery Validation plugin. In your view, you can use the  Html.ValidationMessage or Html.ValidationMessageFor helper methods that will allow your application show error messages whenever validation fails

Here's a link to a post that may be of further assistance.
http://goo.gl/Jxozv